# Java :: Using generics to instantiate an "at runtime" Multi-Comparator

Tags: java, generics, comparator

I have a MultiComparator class that allows one to combine multiple sorts.  For example, the code below creates a sort for Contacts.

```
// This works
contactList.sort(
    new MultiComparator<>(
      new ContactComparator(ContactComparator.Sort.CONTACT_NAME),
      new ContactComparator(ContactComparator.Sort.ID)
    )
);
```

However, I am needed to create the sort order on the fly at runtime, and I am having trouble figuring out how to do this as the java compiler keeps giving me an error: "Cannot infer arguments (unable to resolve constructor)".  For simplicity, I have omitted the logic that would create the "ordered" List of sort fields, but assume that the user could create the order. My issue becomes, how to create the MultiComparator given this ordered List.  Any ideas?

```
List<ContactComparator> orderedContactComparators = new ArrayList();   // assume this was created above
contactList.sort(
    // compiler error: "Cannot infer arguments (unable to resolve constructor)
    new MultiComparator<>(orderedContactComparators)
);
```

For reference, the other classes are below...

### ContactComparator Class

```
public class ContactComparator implements Comparator<Contact> {

    private Sort currentSort;
    private boolean sortAsc;

    public enum Sort {
        NAME, ADDRESS, ID
    }

    public ContactComparator() {
        currentSort = Sort.NAME;
        sortAsc = true;
    }

    public ContactComparator(Sort sort) {
        currentSort = Objects.requireNonNullElse(sort, Sort.NAME);
        sortAsc = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Contact o1, Contact o2){
        // Compare logic here
    }

}
```

### MultiComparator Class

```
public class MultiComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private List<Comparator<? super T>> comparators;

    public MultiComparator(List<Comparator<? super T>> comparators) {
        this.comparators = comparators;
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public MultiComparator(Comparator<? super T>... comparators) {
        this(Arrays.asList(comparators));
    }

    public int compare(T o1, T o2) {
        for (Comparator<? super T> c : comparators) {
            int result = c.compare(o1, o2);
            if (result != 0) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return ObjectUtils.compare(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());
    }

    @SafeVarargs
    public static <T> void sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T>... comparators) {
        list.sort(new MultiComparator<T>(comparators));
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you have to initialize the list as `List<ContactComparator> orderedContactComparators = new ArrayList<>();` add these `<>`

Comment: Add a type parameter to the construction of `MultiComparator` as you use `List<Comparator<? super T>>` the compiler can not infere the type (as it can be anything `? super T`). Use `new MultiComparator<ContactComparator>(..)`

Comment: Note that since Java 8, you can use `new ContactComparator(ContactComparator.Sort.CONTACT_NAME) .thenComparing(new ContactComparator(ContactComparator.Sort.ID))` to combine them. Or for a non-empty list, use `orderedContactComparators.stream().reduce(Comparator::thenComparing).get()` So this `MultiComparator` is obsolete.

Comment: @Holger thanks for the info on Java 8 methods... Still getting a compiler error thought with the following (reduced) code fragment:              `List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
            List<ContactComparator> orderedContactComparators = new ArrayList<>();
            orderedContactComparators.add(new ContactComparator(ContactComparator.Sort.NAME));
            contactList.sort(orderedContactComparators.stream().reduce(Comparator::thenComparing));`

Comment: @Holger `Error is: Bad return type in method reference: cannot convert java.util.Comparator<com.afs.entity.Contact> to com.afs.util.comparator.ContactComparator`  Error is at the "Comparator::thenComparator" section

Comment: The easiest fix is to change the declaration to `orderedContactComparators` from `List<ContactComparator>` to `List<Comparator<Contact>>`

Comment: @Holger thanks for all your quick responses.  I made those changes, but getting another compiler error... `List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<>();
List<Comparator<Contact>> orderedContactComparators = new ArrayList<>();
orderedContactComparators.add(new ContactComparator(ContactComparator.Sort.NAME));
contactList.sort(orderedContactComparators.stream().reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)); // Error on this line`  error: `sort (java.util.Comparator<? super com.afs.entity.Contact>)
in List cannot be applied to (java.util.Optional<java.util.Comparator<com.afs.entity.Contact>>)`

Comment: I think I figured it out...  `contactList.sort(orderedContactComparators.stream().reduce(Comparator::thenComparing).orElse(null));`